# Customize Date/Time title for Final Cut Pro X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, motion

I am trying to "recreate" FCPX's title *Date/Time* in Apple Motion 5. Reason is that the the original Title is in English. I want the date to be at least numeric only (26.10.2016).

I am able to achieve this in new Final Cut Title, but then in FCPX the title does not use time of the connected clip in Timeline.

I also tried to open the original Title in Apple Motion, but I am unable to find any setting of date generator value. Also in this title I am unable to change region of the the date.

Region control for my Time date generator
[image: Region control for my Time date generator]

No region control for Time date generator from original title
[image: No region control for Time date generator from original title]

Update:
I was able to change the region in Motion, but it is not reflected in FCPX and the Title goes crazy

[image: Date/time behavior after change in Motion]

Answer (score 1):

The reason the one from Final Cut Pro doesn't have the "Region" control is because it has the "Animate" flag set. If you set the animate flag on yours, then select something else, and then select yours again, the Region setting goes away. I don't know if that's a bug or if there's some user interface design reason for it.

So if you want to change the region, I suggest turning on the animate flag, select something else, select the generator again and set the region. Then turn the animate flag off again. I'm not sure if it will take or not, but I bet it would.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I did not work much. I was able to change the region, but I don't like the result ;) (see Update of question)

Answer (score 1):

This effect is not editable. If you make a copy, it won't work.

Actually the title does not go crazy. All it does is, if "Animate" is ticked, go from "Start" to "End" timestamps as fast as needed depending on the effect duration in your timeline.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to edit this date & time title:

- edit a copy of the date & time title in the common way using motion
- rename the copied and edited *.moti file in the user template path to "Date:Time.moti". It will be displayed in finder as "Date/Time.moti"
- rename (with admin rights) the "Date:Time.moti" (displayed as "Date/Time.moti) to "Date:Time.moti_save" in the original template path "/Applications/Final Cut Pro.app/Contents/PlugIns/MediaProviders/MotionEffect.fxp/Contents/Resources/Templates.localized/Titles.localized/Lower Thirds.localized/Date:Time.localized". This is only for safety reasons to have a way back to the old configuration
- copy (with admin rights) the edited and renamed "Date:Time.moti" file from the user template path to the original path above
- now Final Cut Pro will use the edited "Date:Time.moti" file and everything should work as aspected